# How to remove checkbox from array in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Trying to create a function that will remove the selected checkbox items from the array but can't seem to figure it out. I have tried using splice and .pop() but it just won't remove the items I select. I think the best way would be to use an if statement but I do not know how to write it so that it shows true or false. Please help!!!

JS:

```
.controller('toDoCtrl', function($scope, toDoFactory){
    //set $scope variables
    $scope.tasks = toDoFactory.tasks;
    $scope.removeTasks = toDoFactory.removeTasks;
})
.factory('toDoFactory', ['$http', function($http){
    var toDo = {
        tasks: [],
        removeTasks: function(selectedTask){
            angular.forEach(toDo.tasks, function(value, selectedTask){
                var i = toDo.tasks.indexOf(value);
                toDo.tasks.splice(toDo.tasks.indexOf(i), 1);
            });
        }
    };  
    return toDo;
}])
```

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="removeTasks()">Remove</button>
```

Comment: can you show us some more code?

Comment: you are finding wrong `value` you should find `indexOf(selectedTask)` and you are not passing `selectedTask` from calling of `factory` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not really understood if you wanted to delete all selected tasks or just one.
Anyway, you can do this for example :

JS:

```
app
.controller('toDoCtrl', function($scope, toDoFactory){
    //set $scope variables
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.data = toDoFactory.data;
    $scope.removeTasks = toDoFactory.removeTasks;
    $scope.removeTask = toDoFactory.removeTask;
})
.factory('toDoFactory', ['$http', function($http){
    var toDo = {
        data : {
          tasks: [
            {text: "hello world", done: false},
            {text: "hello world2", done: false},
            {text: "hello world3", done: false}
          ]
        },
        removeTasks: function(){
          toDo.data.tasks = toDo.data.tasks.filter(function(task){
            return !task.done;
          });
        }, 
        removeTask: function(index){
          toDo.data.tasks.splice(index, 1);
        },
    };  
    return toDo;
}]);
```

HTML:

```
  <body ng-controller="toDoCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat='task in data.tasks'>
    <input type='checkbox' ng-model='task.done' />
    <span>{{task.text}}</span>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <button ng-click="removeTasks()">Remove</button>

  </body>
```

Plunkr :
https://plnkr.co/edit/bTG0fEUZl1uoTIFT1NhC?p=preview